# Would my paper be published if I missed the conference due to visa-related problems?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, paper-submission, publishers

I have two accepted papers in one conference . The problem is that until I have not gotten an original invitation letter, a must to get a visa. I've sent over ten emails to the email addresses listed on the conference website to the organizers and chairperson asking for this letter; no response. I do not have anyone else who can present in my place. If I failed to attend the conference because of this, would my papers be published in the conference proceedings?

Comment: The OP is more patient than I would be. Long before the tenth e-mail, I would be working my network - find someone I know who knows someone involved in organizing the conference and ask them to push.

Comment: I only see one e-mail address listed at the website, under "Contact", an address of the type "info@...". Maybe there is an issue with this address. As an alternative, you can google the institution e-mail addresses of the involved persons, specifically, the general chair and the conference coordinators.

Comment: Generally, if you are doing research in the area of a conference, you will personally know some of the people working in that area, who will know people involved in the conference. Most academic research communities are "small worlds". People serve on the same program committees. They go to the same conferences. They hire each other's former students. Look for a personal connection, and use that to find out what is going on.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper  I will try to contact the Chair institution , hopefully there as an enough time to find a solution . Thank you very much.

Comment: @Paulo: You're welcome! Hope that can sort out the issues. Just to clarify, my comment mentions three different persons/e-mail addresses: the general chair, and the two conference coordinators (see "Programme Committees" at the website). Each address may be found at the website of the person's home institution.

Comment: Duplicate of **["If a paper is accepted as a poster, must you attend the conference?"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57390/if-a-paper-is-accepted-as-a-poster-must-you-attend-the-conference)** or **[What to do if I can't get a visa to attend a conference that accepted my paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/what-to-do-if-i-cant-get-a-visa-to-attend-a-conference-that-accepted-my-paper)** which in turn references http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/etiquette-when-unable-to-attend-a-conference . Please start closing as duplicates, everyone.

Comment: I removed many of the comments and incorporated that info into the question.

Comment: I am not sure the real question is a duplicate. It turns out there is a complete lack of communication between the OP and the conference. That is the cause of the visa issue, but is also a potential blocker for any of the prior solutions such as video presentation.

Comment: Then shouldn't the title reflect the underlying question *"Conference organizer is failing to send me invitation letter which I need to get visa to attend; how to proceed; will my paper not be published?"*

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: you may be right. However we're swimming in duplicates. As you said really the OP's question should have been been raised months earlier and should have been *""Conference organizer is failing to send me invitation letter which I need to get visa to attend; how to proceed?"*. Better to prevent the problem, than incur the problem. But apparently it's too late now, for this OP.

Comment: Yes , I am too late now, till now after I contacted them again( by phone calls), they haven't sent the invitation letter yet.  I think I am going to lose the publication, my money, and I will have many problems with my supervisor , because of the coordinators' ignorance .

Answer (score 11):

To be part of the proceedings, the paper needs to be presented at the conference.

I have seen two cases where the paper was presented despite physical absence of the authors. In the first case, the paper was presented by one of the authors via a Skype call. In the second case, a befriended researcher of the authors gave the presentation.

Comment: I have seen a similar case, where they played back a video the author sent beforehand (it was for a spotlight talk, so no questions from the audience).